# Getting error 'The app build failed to produce artifact folder:' setting up Azure static web app using GitLab tutorial

Tags: azure, gitlab, blazor, gitlab-ci, azure-static-web-app

While doing this [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/gitlab?tabs=blazor), I ran into an issue running the pipeline, I followed every step and got this error at the end `The app build failed to produce artifact folder: '/builds/GitLabAccount/my-first-static-web-app/wwwroot'. Please ensure this property is configured correctly in your deployment configuration file.`

It looks like it is publishing to `Destination directory: /bin/staticsites/753b0720-d89d-4b25-be31-fd6b5a465688-swa-oryx/app`

I followed the tutorial and got to Step 8 and ran into this error. Do I need to set up the gitlab-ci.yml differently?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I have referred this [MS Tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/gitlab?tabs=blazor) to perform the steps below:-

When I ran the pipeline for the first time with the same .gitlab-ci.yml as the  [tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/gitlab?tabs=blazor) Even I received the same error code during the Pipeline run:-

[image]

> According to this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/front-end-frameworks#configuration) for Blazor projects build artifacts path is relative to the Output of your Publish folder and it needs to be set to `wwwroot` by default.

I ***edited my .gitlab-ci.yml*** like below by setting
`OUTPUT_PATH: 'wwwroot'` :-

```yaml
variables:

API_TOKEN: $DEPLOYMENT_TOKEN

APP_PATH: '$CI_PROJECT_DIR/Client'

OUTPUT_PATH: 'wwwroot'

  

deploy:

stage: deploy

image: registry.gitlab.com/static-web-apps/azure-static-web-apps-deploy

script:

- echo "App deployed successfully."
```

**And the build CI/CD in gitlab was successful, Refer below:-**

[image]

> My Blazor static web app deployed successfully, Refer below:-
>
> [image]