# Deploying static Blazor web app from GitHub

Tags: azure, github, blazor, github-actions

I created a Blazor app with `dotnet new blazor` according to [this tutorial](https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/intro) and tried to deploy it on Azure, but this is not possible.

On Azure with the default settings I get the error message:

```
The app build failed to produce artifact folder: 'example/wwwroot'. Please ensure this property is configured correctly in your workflow file.
```

The Blazor app is in a subfolder `example`, so in the workflow I gave `app_location: "/example/"`.

The `output_location` needs to be set to `wwwroot` (on AWS that is automatically correct, on Azure it has to be manually set).

Then it complains about missing `index.html`:

```
Failed to find a default file in the app artifacts folder (wwwroot). Valid default files: index.html,Index.html.
```

Comment: Refer my SO answer for the same error - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76201397/getting-error-the-app-build-failed-to-produce-artifact-folder-setting-up-azur/76206180#76206180

Comment: Configure output path to wwwroot- https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/get-started-portal?tabs=blazor&pivots=github Refer this MS document

Comment: Check your folder structure is similar to this Github repository -https://github.com/staticwebdev/blazor-basic/tree/main/Client

Comment: That repository is several years out of date. In newly created Blazor projects today, there exists no `index.html`. I'm working off the official example, where there is no `index.html`, what one sees in that repo is instead in `App.razor` and what one sees in `App.razor` is instead in `Routes.razor`. So `index.html` -> `App.razor` -> `Routes.razor`.

Comment: Let me try with the new Blazor app and Push it to Azure Static Web app via Github actions and get back

Comment: I created the app with `dotnet new blazor -o example` and not by checking out an example repository: https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/learn/aspnet/blazor-tutorial/intro

Comment: Okay, I'll do the same

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to this [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/static-web-apps/front-end-frameworks?source=recommendations), **Azure Static Web app only supports Blazor WASM application** and **not the Blazor web app that gets created with `dotnet new blazor` command**.

I tried deploying the normal blazor  web app in Azure static web app and received the same error code as yours, Then I created a sample **`Blazor WASM (WebAssembly standalone app)`** app and tried to deploy it in Azure Static Web app, It worked successfully.

***Blazor WASM app:-***

[image]

***Azure Static Web app Github Action Workflow:-***

```yaml
name: Azure Static Web Apps CI/CD

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - master
  pull_request:
    types: [opened, synchronize, reopened, closed]
    branches:
      - master

jobs:
  build_and_deploy_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'push' || (github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action != 'closed')
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Build and Deploy Job
    steps:
      - uses: actions/checkout@v3
        with:
          submodules: true
          lfs: false
      - name: Build And Deploy
        id: builddeploy
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_POLITE_MUSHROOM_0EE789C03 }}
          repo_token: ${{ secrets.GITHUB_TOKEN }} 
          action: "upload"
          app_location: "/" 
          api_location: "" 
          output_location: "wwwroot" 

  close_pull_request_job:
    if: github.event_name == 'pull_request' && github.event.action == 'closed'
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest
    name: Close Pull Request Job
    steps:
      - name: Close Pull Request
        id: closepullrequest
        uses: Azure/static-web-apps-deploy@v1
        with:
          azure_static_web_apps_api_token: ${{ secrets.AZURE_STATIC_WEB_APPS_API_TOKEN_POLITE_MUSHROOM_0EE789C03 }}
          action: "close"
```

**Output:-**

[image]

[image]

[image]

In order to Depoy your Blazor Web app. Create Azure Web app service instead of Azure static Web app and deploy your app there, refer below:-

[image]

***The Blazor Web app got deployed successfully:-***

[image]

***For Github  Action Deployment in Azure Web App:-***

After the Web app is created> **`Visit Deployment Center > Select Source as Github > Your Blazor web app Github Repository and click Save:`**-

The Web App deployment  via Github Actions will start and succeed:-

[image]