# Convert a Blazor app created by dotnet new blazor to Blazor WASM

Tags: .net, blazor, blazor-webassembly

I have created a Blazor app with the command `dotnet new blazor`.

However, deployment as a static web app fails with the message `index.html missing`.

This is because [the app created by `dotnet new blazor` needs to be deployed non-statically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77831933/deploying-static-blazor-web-app-from-github).

I could do that.

But I would want to know if and how I could migrate a Blazor app created with `dotnet new blazor` to a Blazor WASM app.

By comparing to [this repository](https://github.com/staticwebdev/blazor-basic/tree/main/Client), we see that the following files correspond:

| `dotnet new blazor` | WASM |
| --- | --- |
| `App.razor` | `index.html` |
| `Routes.razor` | `App.razor` |

Additionally, I replaced the code in the `Program.cs`.

However, the build then fails with this error messages:

```
error CS0246: The type or namespace name 'BlazorBasic' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

error CS0234: The type or namespace name 'WebAssembly' does not exist in the namespace 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components' (are you missing an assembly reference?)
```

I thought adjusting the `_Imports.razor` would help, but it only got worse (really long list of error messages, so I'm not putting it).

So what do I need to change to make an app created with `dotnet new blazor` be executable as a Blazor WASM app?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you create an empty `Standalone Blazor Web Assembly` project and start populating it "manually" from your current project.

The Standalone wasm is way simpler as it does not have server-side stuff nor rendering modes - it is always WASM. As you noticed, entry point is via index.html -> App.razor.

I believe, at least, currently you are missing the WebAssembly NuGet packages? These must probably be added
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly`
and
`Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.WebAssembly.DevServer`. But I think this becomes more clear when you compare the two and start doing the "manual labor".

Comment: But where do I add the Nuget packages? They need to be mentioned in some file so it can be restored when checking out the project on the CI.

Comment: And how do I create a new standalone Blazor Web Assembly project when I'm not using Visual Studio but the command line?

Comment: `dotnet new blazorwasm` NuGet package references are always added to the .csproj file. You don't need to edit the file manually, you can use `dotnet add <package> --version <version>` command