# How to get ASP.NET Core 8 Blazor Web App (without index.html) to run hosted in GitHub Pages

Tags: asp.net-core, blazor, github-pages

In an ASP.NET Core 7 Blazor WebAssembly app, I had everything working well hosting on GitHub Pages via Actions deploying with the help of `JamesIves/github-pages-deploy-action@v4`

But after upgrading to ASP.NET Core 8 and [converting it to a Blazor Web App](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/migration/70-80?view=aspnetcore-8.0&tabs=visual-studio#convert-a-hosted-blazor-webassembly-app-into-a-blazor-web-app), it uses a App.razor file in the server project instead of index.html.  Index.html is deleted.

I think GitHub Pages needs an index.html to work at all, right?  **How do I get my Blazor Web App to work in GitHub Pages without index.html?**  If I just try it the same way as in the Blazor WebAssembly app, I get the 404 page, and I assume that's because I have no index.html.  Any suggestions?

Comment: If you already have a Net7 standalone application, then create a net8 Standalone Application and look at what changes between the Net7 and net8 templates.  I don't think a lot.  The *Blazor Web App* template is the old Server/WebAssembly hosted template, with pre-rendering in  *WebAssembly*.

Answer (score 1):

GitHub pages supports static hosting only. A "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App" can be hosted on GitHUb pages because it is just static files. But a "Blazor Web App", which is what your app is, is incompatible because it needs to run a .Net process to work.

Either convert your app to a "Blazor WebAssembly Standalone App" to be compatible with GitHub pages, try a VPS (Ex. [Amazon Lightsail](https://aws.amazon.com/lightsail/)), or maybe try [Microsoft Azure](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/free#all-free-services). Both have some free offerings or trials.

Comment: Perfect, that makes sense.  How can I convert my app to "standalone"?  A few searches don't reveal much.  Just start over?

Comment: Someone already asked how to do that and accepted an answer: [Convert a Blazor app created by dotnet new blazor to Blazor WASM](https://stackoverflow.com/a/77841504/3786270) 